# PHP: How to use date interval for a stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this php script that executes a stored procedure. I am retrieving the StoredProcedure that takes two parameter values.

**Problem:**

How can I put lets say: the actual day past 10 minutes? So, I want the every 10 minute old record.
Is this possible even though this StoredProcedure has been provided to me only for readable access with a start and end date as paramaters?

Thanks in advance

PHP:

```
    //DATE values to replace in parameters
    $start_date = "2014-11-11";
    $end_date   = "2014-11-12"; 

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_overlay_result)){
        $sp_value = $row['query']; 
    }

    //replacing parameter values for Dates
    $sp_value = str_replace('start_date',$start_date,$sp_value);
    $sp_value = str_replace('end_date',$end_date,$sp_value);
```

Stored Procedure: It is in a different server, so I saved the actual String value of the SP in my table "overlay" like so: **CALL telephony.sp_get_spec_stat_all_agents( 'start_date', 'end_date')**

```
    //Overlay table
    $query_overlay_sql    = "SELECT query FROM overlays";
    //prepare query
    $query_overlay_result = mysqli_query($dbh1,$query_overlay_sql);
```

I then execute the SP by retrieving two values that I need to join tables from different servers.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbh2_result)){   
        $memo[] = array( "username"  => $row['memo_code'],
                         "aht_value" => $row['avg_handle_time']
                       );
}
```

Hope this clarifies things

Comment: It is not obvious what the `str_replace()` lines are used for.  If I understand the rest of your question, you want to be able to supply start/end dates within 10 minutes of now, but can't modify the SQL code? If that's the case, you can determine the correct time values in PHP using a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) object

Comment: Are you trying to query a query from the database?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes you understood my question correctly. I cannot modify the SQL code.

Comment: @SamDufel the stored procedure is saved as an actual value in a table that I created. From there Im reading it and replacing the parameter values

Comment: @alda1234 Just so we're certain how the SP is being called, can you post the code you use to call the procedure? That may affect how dates get generated. Note also, that if the values in the target table are of a `DATE` type rather than `DATETIME`, they won't have the necessary resolution to limit the way you want.

Comment: Ohhh, your last comment sounds like a very strange way of executing SQL, and does not sound like what a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) actually is (it's a SQL program stored in the RDBMS and executed by passing params to the RDBMS rather than a SQL string). Please post a little more code so we can see it.

Comment: Ok will post it, hold on

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I added the code hope it clarifies

Comment: Okay, so the SQL string you have stored, and are executing is the `CALL` statement, which does call a real stored procedure on a different server, it appears. The purpose of your two `str_replace()` calls are to replace the strings `start_date/end_date` in the `CALL` string with date values, correct?

Comment: yes you understood my code correctly, that's exactly what I am doing

Comment: Last question for clarification - do you want records created in the past 10 minutes, or records created more than 10 minutes ago, and if more than 10 ago, with what starting date, today's date?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  I want the records **created in the past 10 minutes of the actual day** So lets day today is November 17 show records past 10 minutes only. Thanks for the help I appreciate your interest of my post!

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to store the name of the prepared statement in the database.

The simpler approach is to run the prepared statement directly:

```
$sql = 'CALL telephony.sp_get_spec_stat_all_agents(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE, NOW())';
$query_overlay_result = mysqli_query($dbh2, $sql);
```

Comment: Yep, easier than the long answer I was just working on, using `?` with PHP date values...

Comment: If you really _must_ store the `CALL` statement in your table (seems like there's only one statement in there, so maybe you don't need to), then you would use your `str_replace()` process to replace `start_time` with `NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE` and your end time with `NOW()` (removing the single quotes on both). It would be _much_ less complicated to just execute the `CALL` statement from a string in your PHP code as in Sam's answer though.

Comment: the reason that I am actually saving the SP in a table its because theres other fields that I will use later on. Also, I am executing the SP from the different server with another connection as you can see in my code above "dbh2" .. I tried plugging in just **CALL telephony.sp_get_spec_stat_all_agents( NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE, NOW())**  but returns no result whatsoever.

Comment: Actually, I don't see you executing any queries against a `$dbh2` in the code you posted.

Comment: thsi is what I am doing, doesnt work: **$sp_value = "CALL telephony.sp_get_spec_stat_all_agents(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE, NOW())";

  $dbh2_result = mysqli_query($dbh2, $sp_value) 
   or die("Query stored_procedure fail: " . mysqli_error($dbh2));
   
   
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbh2_result)){   
   $memo[] = array( "username"  => $row['memo_code'],
                     "aht_value" => $row['avg_handle_time']
                    );
  }**

Comment: I tried using the SQL command directly in the database but returns no values when there are. what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you inserting dates in the same timezone as the DB server?

Comment: if I do this it works: **CALL telephony.sp_get_spec_stat_all_agents( '2014-11-02', '2014-11-02' );**